# How do I get a location from a click event menu button in wechat

Tags: php, xml, wechat

I am trying to develop a simple response to a wechat user defined menu button that generates a click event. the response is an static map image of the senders location. I have the response working in testing to a sent location message and returning the rich media response with the url of the static map. What I need is for the Event click to fire the location message that my site will respond to. I can't seem to find where to set the actions that the button would execute. can anyone help, sorry if I'm not clear enough.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To get a user's location from a click event you would need a few things.

1. Your menu item needs to of type click

   "button":[
    {
         "type":"click",
         "name":"Get Location",
         "key":"location"
     }]
2. Next you would need to setup a auto response for the keyword "location" that would return the user's location
3. You need to enable user location settings on admin.wechat.com first. Go to Service -> My Service. Under Advanced API enable "Obtain the user's location(Disabled)"
4. Look at the documentation here to get the user's location: http://admin.wechat.com/wiki/index.php?title=User_Location